# one HTML page within another?

Tags: html

For example I have a main page with a div ( or something of that kind ) within which I want a content page to appear. What do you think would be the best way of doing this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using PHP, `include('page2.php')` is the best way to. if not, `<iframe src="page2.html"></iframe>` is good.

Answer (score 2):

You can use iframe to achieve this.
check this:
http://www.w3schools.com/TAGS/tag_iframe.asp

Comment: Please note that w3schools might be good to learn and try out but remember, do not to believe everything you read. Here is a link that shows critics' views: http://w3fools.com/